# Excel: How to change the default ordering in Excel Format Control

Tags: excel, button, formatting

I have radio buttons bunched in a group together they are in the order

o NA o 1  o 2  o 3 o 4  o 5

Depending on which radio button the user selects I want to input the value in a different worksheet. However I find that when user selects 'NA' I get 1 , when he select 1 I get '2' & so forth. I tried looking in format control to see if that makes a difference but could'nt see anything . Please let me know how I can do this.

-S

Hello Sathish,

I tried this but it did not change:

```
    Sub GroupBox2563_Click()
    If OptionButton2557.Value = True Then Sheets("Data").Range("F14").Value = 0 
    If OptionButton2558.Value = True Then Sheets("Data").Range("F14").Value = 1
    If OptionButton2559.Value = True Then Sheets("Data").Range("F14").Value = 2 
    If OptionButton2560.Value = True Then Sheets("Data").Range("F14").Value = 3 
    End Sub
```

With Regards
Sri

Answer (score 0):

May be this tutorial will help you.

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-buttons.html.

Follow steps in the above link.

If you want values to be displayed in active sheet then u can use below code.

```
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Range("D3").Value = 1 ' displays 1 in the activesheet in D3 cell
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then Range("D3").Value = 2 ' displays 2 in the activesheet in D3 cell
```

in Another sheet (example Sheet2) Use this

```
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value = 1 ' display 1 in sheet2 in D3 cell
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value = 2 ' display 1 in sheet2 in D3 cell
```

**Updated :** **- Dont do it in GroupBox click event write it in individual Option box click event like below**

```
Sub OptionButton2557_Click()
If OptionButton2557.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value = 1 
End Sub


Sub OptionButton2558_Click()
If OptionButton2558.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").Value = 2 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but the document does not throw light on how to reset the default value & ensure that the value is put in another worksheet